# Replacing the data in dojox.grid.enhancedGrid

Tags: dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dojox.grid

I have created a dojox.grid.EnhancedGrid. The grid is working fine.
In some of the rows when the data for any column is blank/null is there, It is shown in grid with 3 dots(...).  Is there any way to replace those blank dots with blank(no dots).
Or Is it possible to replace a specific value returned from the server with another value.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried to check the values of the cells before they are inserted? If there's no value, you can set your own.

Comment: @^ Thats pretty obvious. I guess, the question is whether there is a way to tell the grid to display some default value (eg. empty string) instead of 3 dots format, when that fields value is missing for any row.

Answer (score 0):

There's a good answer to your Question here:

http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2011-November/060153.html

You just overwrite the default value of the cell. If it's empty you can set the default like this:

```
{name:"num", field: "numbez",'width': '150px','visibility': 'true','defaultValue':''}
```

and instead of the three dots, there wil be an empty cell.

Regards